# Using a for loop to make a cartopy plot of lines from different latitude and longitude coordinates from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, cartopy

The goal for my code is to make a rough roadmap using the latitude and longitude of the exits on the pennsylvania turnpike drawing a line between each exit.

I am using a for loop to plot a line on the map every time it loops. This works if i hard code the latitude and longitude but as soon as i plug in my variables nothing gets plotted. Since the coordinates are in order I am just increasing the index every time it loops to get the next coordinates. I have printed the variables inside the loop and verified they have the desired value. I have tried putting the values in ordered pairs but the plot function didn't like me using nparrays. I'm not sure if there is something simple i am missing, but I appreciate any input.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Open the file for highway metadata to read csv data
highway_metadata = open('milestone3data.csv', 'r')
metafile = csv.reader(highway_metadata, delimiter = ',')

# Create empty lists with highway data
highway_loc = []
highway_name = []
highway_lat = []
highway_lon = []
highway_dist = []

# Loop to transfer the csv file's data into the lists
for i in metafile:
    highway_loc.append(i[0])
    highway_name.append(i[1])
    highway_lat.append(float(i[2]))
    highway_lon.append(float(i[3]))
    highway_dist.append(i[4])

def road_map():

    enhighway_lat = enumerate(highway_lat)
    enhighway_lon = enumerate(highway_lon)
    orthographic = ccrs.Orthographic()
    platecarree = ccrs.PlateCarree()
    proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = -75, central_latitude = 41)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
  # Set up the background
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.STATES)
    ax.set_extent((-85,-70,36,45),crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    for i,j in enhighway_lat:
        for k,l in enhighway_lon:
            if i or k <= 30:
                plt.plot([highway_lon[k], highway_lon[k+1]], [highway_lat[i], highway_lat[i+1]], color='black', linewidth=1, marker='o', markersize=3, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    plt.savefig('cartopytest7.png')
    plt.show
road_map()

[This is my most recent output from the program][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgFrN.png
```

CSV file contents: (mile marker, name of exit, latitude, longitude, miles from beginning of turnpike)

```
2,Gateway (Ohio Connection),40.90419167,-80.47158333,1.43
10,New Castle,40.83018056,-80.34196111,10.7
13,Beaver Valley,40.8143,-80.307925,12.87
28,Cranberry,40.67983889,-80.09537778,28.47
30,Warrendale,40.65533889,-80.06116667,31
39,Butler Valley,40.60913611,-79.91924444,39.1
48,Allegheny Valley,40.542025,-79.81022222,47.73
57,Pittsburgh,40.43808889,-79.74956944,56.44
67,Irwin,40.31342778,-79.65476111,67.22
75,New Stanton,40.22173333,-79.59573333,75.39
91,Donegal,40.10915,-79.35231944,90.69
110,Somerset,40.02033056,-79.05208056,109.91
146,Bedford,40.05013889,-78.48615,145.5
161,Breezewood,39.98721667,-78.24472778,161.5
180,Fort Littleton,40.05010556,-77.93954444,179.44
189,Willow Hill,40.09674167,-77.78441389,188.59
201,Blue Mountain,40.15755278,-77.58403333,201.29
226,Carlisle,40.22814722,-77.14782222,226.54
236,Gettysburg Pike,40.19569444,-76.95665556,236.22
242,Harrisburg West Shore,40.21216667,-76.85765278,241.87
247,Harrisburg East,40.21501111,-76.78060278,247.38
266,Lebanon-Lancaster,40.22974444,-76.43095,266.45
286,Reading,40.21805,-76.05189167,286.09
298,Morgantown,40.15990278,-75.88311667,298.33
312,Downingtown,40.06838611,-75.66450278,311.93
320,SR29,40.07641667,-75.52881944,319.33
326,Valley Forge,40.09296667,-75.39591111,326.62
333,Norristown,40.11101111,-75.27921389,333.28
339,Fort Washington,40.13231944,-75.17092222,338.36
340,Virginia Dr,40.13854444,-75.16268611,339.8
343,Willow Grove,40.16166111,-75.11271111,342.91
351,Bensalem,40.13200278,-74.96229444,351.49
352,Street Rd,40.13150833,-74.96445,351.89
353,Neshaminy Falls,40.12916667,-74.94150278,352.67
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when doing this?

Comment: no it runs without any errors, but does not plot any of the lines.

Comment: I think you need to convert the values you are reading from your csv file to float. Right now you are just feeding them as strings into your  lists `high_was_loc, high_way_lat,` etc. So you need to do `highway_lat.append(float(i[2]))`

Comment: okay I tried that but the output stayed the same.

Comment: did you print `highway_lat` and `highway_lon`? do those have values?

Comment: yes, they have the correct values in the correct order.

Comment: can you add to your post an example of the csv file?

Comment: i think i did already unless i didnt do it right (I am new to this). It should be the first link.

Comment: you added an image and is not showing. Also images of data are not good enough, you are basically asking other people trying to help you to manually write this values down when you could just copy and paste them into the post

Comment: I think the issue here is that you're manually incrementing i and k inside your for loop; iterating over the eumerated lists will increment i and k by default

Comment: Okay, i understand it should be updated, The spaces between each line are not actually in the file

Comment: I have found that if I dont increment it I get an infinite loop of the first values over and over

Comment: because the `while` should be an `if`

Comment: also, i'd suggest using a pandas dataframe to load in the data, would make code much easier to read

Comment: okay i got rid of the incrementing inside the loop and changed it to an if statement but it has not changed the output. Also the arbitrary "30" is temporary until it works using the first 30 or so exits.

Comment: UPDATE: Thank you for everyone's help so far, I was mistaken and the suggestions did actually change the output. It's not exactly what I need but it is a huge improvement, it is plotting the lines on the map but just next to each other and not connected to the previous lines. The updated output screenshot is in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, based on the discussion above, see below for a solution.

Notes:

- Am using pandas DataFames to easily work with the `.csv` file. the `names` field is the column names.
- Am not using orthographic projection at all.
- <strike>Am iterating through the list of highway exits one exit at a time; at each index, am extracting the current and next exits' data - am sure there's a more 'pythonic' way to do this, but this is readable at least.</strike>
- edit: the final index in the loop is length-1
- Update: Thanks to @SimonWillerton, I've removed the loop.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import pandas as pd

def road_map():    
    # Open the file for highway metadata to read csv data
    highway_metadata = pd.read_csv('milestone3data.csv', names=["loc", "name", "lat", "lon", "dist"])

    proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude = -75)
    ax   = plt.axes(projection=proj)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.STATES)
    ax.set_extent((-85,-70,36,45),crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    
    plt.plot(highway_metadata['lon'], highway_metadata['lat'], \
             color='black', linewidth=1, marker='o', markersize=3, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
                       
    plt.savefig('cartopytest7.png')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    road_map()
```

This produces the following image:
[image: highway_connected]

And, based on this image of the Pennsylvania Turnpike from Wikipedia (source=https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pennsylvania_Turnpike_map.svg#file) I think we have success
[image: wiki_pennsylvania_turnpike]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome! Please select as the correct answer (and upvote!) if it solved the problem :)

Comment: As per my answer, you can simplify by getting rid of the for loop and just feeding the 'lon' and 'lat' columns directly into the plot statement.

Comment: `plt.plot(highway_metadata["lon"], highway_metadata["lat"], color='red',  linewidth=1, marker='o', markersize=3, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())`

Comment: @SimonWillerton You're right! Awesome. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looked like you were trying to do something rather complicated with your `plt.plot()` statement.  You have the list of longitudes and the list of lattitudes; that's all you need for plotting between the points in matplotlib, there's no need for `enumerate` or looping over lists.  The following line should do the trick.

```py
plt.plot(highway_lon, highway_lat, color='black', linewidth=1, marker='o', markersize=3, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Here's the code with some unecessary bits removed.

```py
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Open the file for highway metadata to read csv data
highway_metadata = open('milestone3data.csv', 'r')
metafile = csv.reader(highway_metadata, delimiter = ',')

# Create empty lists with highway data
highway_loc = []
highway_name = []
highway_lat = []
highway_lon = []
highway_dist = []

# Loop to transfer the csv file's data into the lists
for i in metafile:
    highway_loc.append(i[0])
    highway_name.append(i[1])
    highway_lat.append(float(i[2]))
    highway_lon.append(float(i[3]))
    highway_dist.append(i[4])

def road_map():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = -75, 
                             central_latitude = 41)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
    ax.set_extent((-85,-70,36,45),crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    # Set up the background
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.STATES)

    plt.plot(highway_lon, highway_lat, 
             color='black', linewidth=1, marker='o', markersize=3, 
             transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    plt.savefig('cartopytest7.png')
    plt.show
    
road_map()
```